# Web based interface to run docker images

Tags: docker, containers

I am looking to build a system in which I can run a docker container from web browser and then get a terminal on browser itself to interact with the container.

Idea is to give a web based interface for users to practice python or other programming language without having to do the installation locally.

Are there any open source systems which do something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is to broad.

I kind of see what you want to do, but this is basically a complex system that involves (for example):

1. Installing Docker Engine
2. Defining a few Docker Images in advance
3. Having a server app able to start/stop/create containers
4. Having a web interface that can send request to this server to manipulate containers
5. Having a web interface (same or not as above) to connect to the containers

I feel that this is a complex system that can't be answered as a whole in a Stack Overflow question. You might want to break down your question in small pieces first.

That said, there are a few resources that we can maybe recommend.

- For point 2, if you use NodeJS, there is a module that I like called dockerode https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode
- For point 4 and 5, this is similar to what portainer does http://portainer.io/

Also it depends how far you want a tailor-made solution or not. There might be also some online services doing just that.